# Wrap your head around this treasure hunt

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

You are participating in a treasure hunt, with the following instructions:

> ```
>    X N F  
>  I       I  
> S    +    N  
>  I       G  
>    B W P
> ```
>
> 1. Tired sunrays
> 2. Not the sheep belonging to the departed
> 3. Awesome tune
> 4. Mysterious healer
> 5. Not the king nor the barbarian creation
> 6. Musical chairs
> 7. After a Moon
> 8. Dark leafy word boxes
> 9. Simon says
> 10. Imaginary fruit flesh
> 11. IT company with a hot cup
> 12. Muhammad Ali
> 13. Jamaican peer-to-peer enthusiasts
>
> *The treasure hunt starts a 3 o'clock from Birmingham, facing London or Manchester*

---

**Where is the treasure and what is it?**

Hint:

> At two it's nearly winter, after an hour stand by the order

Hint2:

> Look for movies/series

Comment: For clue 13, is the misspelling of "enthusiasts" intentional? For clue 12, if this refers to the famous boxer, he spelled his name *Muhammad* Ali. (If it refers to the common Arabic name with variable English transliteration, no problem.)

Comment: My mother tongue got in the way, I'll correct the spellings, thank you ;)

Comment: A hint has been added

Answer (score 1):

I've only got a few of the answers so far, but wanted to put them out there to maybe provide a starting point.

No idea what to do with the circle of letters at this time.

2) Not the sheep belonging to the departed

> Shaun of the Dead

4) Mysterious healer

> Doctor Strange

10) Imaginary fruit flesh

> Pulp Fiction

13) Jamaican peer-to-peer enthusiasts

> Pirates of the Caribbean

Comment: One of them is wrong, but that's a good start :)